# Figuring free spot in heap? Keep track of last insert?

Tags: java, heap

How do you keep track of where to insert into a heap: i think using a function that checks the height of each subtree will degrade the algorithm to O(N) from O(log N).

so do you keep a variable in each node or a varibale in the heap that has the last insert spot(defined how?).

Answer (score 1):

the heap is "almost full" binary tree. so you have only one choice where you should insert the new element, no height check is needed - but a pointer to the location the next element should be inserted to.
this of course is enough to ensure a height of O(logn)